# 1 required positional argument?

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

When I run this code, gives me a `TypeError: countdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'time_left'` time_left is supposed to be 5 because I call the function with the parameter 5.

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')

lblCrono = tkinter.Label(window, text = '', bg = 'white', fg = 'red', font = 'Comic 20', padx = 50, pady = 5)
lblCrono.grid(column = 1, row = 5, sticky = tkinter.S, padx = 100, pady = 150)

def countdown (time_left):

    while time_left >= 0:
        lblCrono.configure(text = str(time_left))
        time_left = time_left - 1
        window.after(1000, countdown)

countdown(5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: But you tell tkinter to call it with no parameters in after().

Answer (score 1):

The while loop inside `countdown()` should be replaced by `if` statement and `time_left` should be passed to `after(...)` as well:

```
def countdown(time_left):
    lblCrono.configure(text=str(time_left))
    if time_left > 0:
        time_left -= 1
        window.after(1000, countdown, time_left)
```